# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id' - Error in on_raw_reaction_add

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py, attributeerror

So I've recently been facing this issue in my bot which I didn't face before...

The error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/container/cogs/mod.py", line 100, in on_raw_reaction_add
    await payload.member.add_roles(role, reason="Reaction Roles", atomic=True)
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/member.py", line 764, in add_roles
    await req(guild_id, user_id, role.id, reason=reason)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

And my code is :

```
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):

        if payload.member.bot:
            pass

        else:
            with open('reactrole.json') as react_file:
                data = json.load(react_file)
                for x in data:
                    if x['emoji'] == payload.emoji.name:
                        role = discord.utils.get(self.client.get_guild(
                            payload.guild_id).roles, id=x['role_id'])

                        await payload.member.add_roles(role)


    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_raw_reaction_remove(self, payload):

        with open('reactrole.json') as react_file:
            data = json.load(react_file)
            for x in data:
                if x['emoji'] == payload.emoji.name:
                    role = discord.utils.get(self.client.get_guild(
                        payload.guild_id).roles, id=x['role_id'])

                    
                    await self.client.get_guild(payload.guild_id).get_member(payload.user_id).remove_roles(role)
```

I just checked the docs and added these extra args like reason and atomic.

If you know the solution to this please answer.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The role you are getting with `discord.utils.get` can somehow not be found, which leads to `discord.utils.get` returning a None object.
The issue therefore lies with the data in the `reactrole.json` file.

Without additional information (like the reactrole.json file and the roles on the server) this is all which can be helped with.

Comment: I actually checked the json file way back.... There's no error in it. I even manually checked and all IDs were correct.